# How to run second vertex ai pipeline after first one is completed successfully?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a certain scenario where I want to deploy two vertex ai pipelines, where the second one is dependent on the first run. Is there a way I can run the second vertex ai pipeline only after first one is completed?

Comment: Did you have a look to Eventarc?

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for a way to trigger the execution of the second pipeline after the first pipeline exits.

In the `ExitHandler` callback of the first pipeline, add a trigger for the second pipeline. You may use a Cloud Pub/Sub based trigger, HTTP trigger via Cloud Functions, or anything that works for you.

Modify this [email notification example to trigger function runs](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/email-notifications) on the first pipeline's execution completion.

Then, adapt from this [example for HTTP trigger via Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/schedule-cloud-scheduler#create_a_cloud_function_with_http_trigger) for starting the second job after completing the first one.

Comment: How do we overwrite the email notification function or change it as per our need?